# Android Wifi Not connecting Automatically when i add a new Wifi Configuration

Tags: android, connection, wifi

I am trying to add a new Wifi Configuration and after saving the configuration i want to Connect it , though i am Able to add it and could connect when i do it by manual Selecting the specific wifi.

I want To connect this saved Wifi configuration automatically without navigating to Wifi Setting page.

please suggest me if there is Any Way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

Please try command below if you have already replaced the WiFi configuration file

Turn on wifi

> `adb shell svc wifi enable`

Turn off wifi

> `adb shell svc wifi disable`

if you are using Android 4.3 Jelly Bean, the wifi configure file is locate in /data/misc/wifi
`wpa.supplicant.conf`

if you are using 4.4 kitkat, the configure files are `wpa.supplicant.conf` and `p2p.supplicant.conf` locate in /data/misc/wifi.